# Should i use a plugin for Event Manager or code my own needs?

Tags: custom-post-types, events

I own a local guide on wordpress, with already many CPT like "hotels, bnb, markets, etc..."

all those CPT are linked by relational field to a city. ( city is CPT as well )

Now, i wish to add a EVENT type to list all events in a city, as well as in other CPT. ( like, you see a hotel page, and i will display all the events near the hotel ).

I don't need much field, like i didn't list any venue, i don't need ticket system, etc...

I just need : "event name, event date, event thumb, event adress, event price, ..." and usual info.

So i'm wondering, should i use a plugin like wp event manager, or should i create a new CPT ?

If i create my CPT, will i be able to list event from the more recent to the more olde (base on event date ?)

Thanks in advance for your advised help !

Comment: Hey! Is there a specific answer you have in mind? This isn't a discussion forum, and you need to be able to mark an answer as not just the most helpful answer, but **the** answer, the canonical definitive answer, that all people who have this question will see and go "Yes, this is the answer". This site is more like a documentation wiki, yet your question is a discussion, and the responses can be varied depending on peoples opinions, it doesn't really fit into the format of the site

Comment: No, there is no specific answear, i just want people opinion as you said. People experience is great to help to make a choice. But you're true, i may better go on a forum. I just wonder what does experts of SE think is the better solution.

Comment: Then by definition there can't be a concrete answer that applies to everybody, **as I said this isn't a discussion forum**, so not all questions fit. You have to be able to mark an answer as canonically, factually correct. That doesn't mean it's not a good question, just not a good question for WPSE

Comment: i understand ! Please do what is the best, if you need to delete the question, no problem !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a tough question that I think you will have to be the one to really answer, but hopefully I can provide some additional insight.

Building events yourself means you will have exactly what you need, but will have to handle all display formats, all inputs and input support (like date/time formatting), and all the fun details that comes with handling dates and times, eg leap years, timezones, multi-day events, etc. It could be a lot of work.

Using a plugin (I'm not thinking of any plugin in particular), you will have to reduce the number of features and potentially customize the display to your needs. There will be a lot of extra cruft in features and templates, but there will be a lot of ways to help as well. Even if you have to customize the display and some of the functionality, with a well-written plugin you should be able to accomplish this. In addition, you will have the benefit of another set of developers that are finding and fixing bugs, keeping the plugin secure, and pushing new features.

Keep in mind, adding a new plugin and integrating your site with it will require some additional time to get familiar with the code.

I hope this helps you make your decision a bit easier.

Comment: Thanks for this reply ! You're true, especially on maintaining multi-day event ! I have no idea to handle this myself. Also for security purposes. I just dont want to surcharge my core app with too many plugins, i coded most of my functions. But for this case, i really don't know what will be the best solution ! I will continue to think at it !

Comment: I definitely understand. Good luck!